# Why is this statement regarding red-black binary search trees true?

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

The Statement: *Suppose that some unsuccessful search in a red-black binary serach tree terminates after k key compares. Then, any unsuccessful search performs at least `ceiling(k/2)` key compares.*

The explanation of why it is correct: *In the extreme case, the links alternate between red and black (starting with red) and the black height is `ceiling(k/2) - 1`. Any unsuccessful search traces a path from the root to a null link; there are exactly `ceiling(k/2) - 1` black links (not including the null link) along such a path. If the path contains no red links, then it contains `ceiling(k/2)` nodes (and makes `ceiling(k/2)` key compares).*

My opinion: unless k = 0 or 1, it is not possible that `k == ceiling(k/2)`. I begin to think maybe the issue is how I interpret the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *some* unsuccessful search takes k compares, then *every* unsuccessful search must take *at least* ceil(k/2) compares.

That includes the one that takes k compares, since k is *at least* ceil(k/2).

Note that "at least" means >=

Comment: you are right, I found myself made a few mistakes by not reading the statement carefully. Thanks a lot.